# Mapping Mandrill JSON webhooks inbound email attachments to C# classes

Tags: c#, json, json.net, mandrill

I can process the JSON webhook inbound emails from Mandrill but not the attachments part of the JSON message.

Here are the C# classes I've created:

```
public class MandrillInbound
{
    public string @event { get; set; }
    public int ts { get; set; }
    public InboundMsg msg { get; set; }
}

public class InboundMsg
{
    public string raw_msg { get; set; }
    //public Headers headers { get; set; }
    public string text { get; set; }
    public bool text_flowed { get; set; }
    public string html { get; set; }
    public List<Attachment> attachments { get; set; }
    public string from_email { get; set; }
    public string from_name { get; set; }
    public List<List<string>> to { get; set; }
    public string subject { get; set; }
    //public Spf spf { get; set; }
    //public SpamReport spam_report { get; set; }
    //public Dkim dkim { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public List<object> tags { get; set; }
    public object sender { get; set; }
    public object template { get; set; }
}

public class Attachment
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string content { get; set; }
    public bool base64 { get; set; }
}
```

The problem seems to be with the format of the JSON from Mandrill for attachments which is as follows:

```
"attachments":{
"Attachment1.txt":{"name":"Attachment1.txt","type":"text\/plain","content":"Test attachment 1","base64":false},
"Attachment2.txt":{"name":"Attachment2.txt","type":"text\/plain","content":"Test attachment 2","base64":false}
}
```

I've contacted Mandrill and they've been very helpful but as a PHP outfit they haven't been able to provide a solution yet.
The specification for the Mandrill inbound email API is here:
https://mandrill.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/205583207-What-is-the-format-of-inbound-email-webhooks-

What do people think the class structure should be to map to the JSON attachments? I use JSON.Net to parse the JSON.

Many thanks

Tim

Comment: Well that helps explain a few things to me, basically why I was getting dictionaries instead of lists. I'm assuming the format for images is the same, could you confirm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define your `InboundMsg` class as follows:

```
public class InboundMsg
{
    // Other properties as before
    Dictionary<string, Attachment> attachments { get; set; }
}
```

Json.NET [can deserialize a JSON object to a .Net generic dictionary, making the property names the dictionary keys and the property values the dictionary values](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingCollections.htm), which is what you want to do here.

Comment: dbc - Thank you, that worked perfectly. Many thanks.